# How to install bottle for both Python2 and Python3 in windows?

Tags: python, bottle

I have installed Python2 and Python3 on my computer, and installed bottle for Python3 via easy_install. For some reason I have to install it for Python2, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
easy_install-2.7 bottle
```

If, for any reason, `easy_install-2.7` is not available on your system, you can also try

```
python2 -m easy_install bottle
```